# Algorand - is there a way to extend the timeout of a transaction?

Tags: javascript, python, algorand

Using Algorand JS or Python libraries, is there a way to extend the timeout of a transaction for more than 1000 rounds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the first valid to be in the future, but it is not possible for a transaction to be valid for over 1000 blocks.